# DBflow make simple relation ship between 2 table

Tags: android, dbflow

DBFlow for android doesn't have good document and after reading more information about how can I make simple relationship between two tables, I'm unable to do that.

I have 2 table as:

`MainCategories` and `SubCategories`

In `SubCategories` I have `channelId` which is stored in `MainCategories`, `MainCategories` has more data on `SubCategories` table, (one to many)

now I'm trying to implementing this relation ship:

My code is not correct and its like with the library documentation

`MainCategories`:

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class ChannelContentCategories extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int channelId;

    @Column
    private String title;

    List<ChannelSubContentCategories> subContentCategories;

    @OneToMany(methods = {OneToMany.Method.ALL})
    public List<ChannelSubContentCategories> getMyChannelSubContentCategoriess() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

`SubCategories`:

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class ChannelSubContentCategories extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int categoryId;

    @Column
    private int parentId;

    @Column
    private String title;

    ...
}
```

how can I make simple relationship between `channelId` on `ChannelContentCategories` table with `parentId` on `ChannelSubContentCategories` table?

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you check this issue, you should use @ForeignKey also
https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/1036

Comment: @Ammar document of this library is not very good and i can't understand me how can i make this relation ship. i think document of that is very old,please see sample of this part of document: `One To Many` in this link: https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/Relationships.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that DBFlow supports `ForeignKey` reference only to `PrimaryKey` column of another table. Therefore, you have a 3 **different** ways to achieve your relationship:

- Move your `@PrimaryKey` in `ChannelContentCategories` from `id` to `channelId`
- Make `parentId` be referenced to `id` instead of `channelId`, therefore no need for `channelId` to be `PrimaryKey`
- Or have multiple primary keys in the table. But in this case you **can't** define your `id` primary key as `autoincremented`

So, I've ended up with the 3rd way, and look what we have:

**ChannelContentCategories.java**

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class ChannelContentCategories extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    public int id;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    public int channelId;

    @Column
    public String title;

    public List<ChannelSubContentCategories> subContentCategories;

    @OneToMany(methods = {OneToMany.Method.ALL}, variableName = "subContentCategories") // this should be equal to the field name, that contains children
    public List<ChannelSubContentCategories> getMyChannelSubContentCategories() {
        if (subContentCategories == null || subContentCategories.isEmpty()) {
            subContentCategories = SQLite.select()
                    .from(ChannelSubContentCategories.class)
                    .where(ChannelSubContentCategories_Table.parentId.eq(channelId))
                    .queryList();
        }
        return subContentCategories;
    }
    ...
}
```

**ChannelSubContentCategories.java**

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class ChannelSubContentCategories extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    @Column
    public int id;

    @Column
    public int categoryId;

    @Column
    @ForeignKey(tableClass = ChannelContentCategories.class,
            references = @ForeignKeyReference(columnName = "parentId", foreignKeyColumnName = "channelId"))
    public int parentId;

    @Column
    public String title;
    ...
}
```

I've tested it and it works. Feel free to choose the most suitable way for you.

Comment: i get this error sir: `Error:*==========*class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.definition.column.ForeignKeyColumnDefinition (Kotlin reflection is not available) :Could not find referenced column channelId from reference named parentId*==========*` for this line of your code: `references = @ForeignKeyReference(columnName = "parentId", foreignKeyColumnName = "channelId"))` i clean up and rebuild again, problem don't resolve

Comment: Well, what version of DBFlow do you use? And have you just copy-pasted all my code? This error means, that you forgot to add `@PrimaryKey` to `channelId` column.

Comment: yes i copy paste, I'm so sorry, i removed primary from id and i added that for `channelId`, i use `4.0.0-beta7` version of that library, i have this problem yet

Comment: Well, I just did the same thing (removed primary key from `id`), and it works for me. Make sure that you have no differences with my code example.

Comment: it seems both of your code and my changed code are the same. ChannelSubContentCategories: `http://paste.debian.net/971902/`  and ChannelContentCategories `http://paste.debian.net/971900/` i get this error now: `Error:*==========*class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.definition.column.ForeignKeyColumnDefinition (Kotlin reflection is not available) :Could not find referenced column channelId from reference named parentId*==========*`

Comment: No they're not the same. Please, be careful. **Firstly**, you should remove `PrimaryKey` annotation above `parentId` field. **Secondly**, you should remove `PrimaryKey` from `id` and add `PrimaryKey` to `channelId` in `ChannelContentCategories` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146963/discussion-between-tux-world-and-rom4ek).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use channelId as foreign key for MainCategories?

like this? :

```
@ForeignKey(tableClass = SubCategories.class)
@Column
private int channelId;
```

Comment: for `ChannelContentCategories` table i have more data on `ChannelSubContentCategories` table which `parentId` in `ChannelSubContentCategories` table is referenced to `channelId` in `ChannelContentCategories` table, yes like with your sample

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to load data from DB and then relate it. Just use SQL statements to combine all this info.

`SELECT column_name.Table_name1, column_name.Table_name2, column_name.Table_name3 FROM Table_name1, Table_name2, Table_name3 WHERE id.Table_name1 == id.Table_name2 && id.Table_name1 == id.Table_name3;`

Hope It'll help